# How to create a email approval workflow in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Once the request is created approval link should be sent to the approver through email and approver should be able to approve through email.

Answer (score 0):

Avinesh,

(It seems like you are asking someone to design a significant module for your Apex application. I think that is a little beyond the scope of this site. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Having said that, I think the trickiest piece is generating the email message links for the "Accept" or "Reject" responses.  If your application doesn't require a lot of security, it could be done fairly simply.

Given that you'd need a page in your Apex application to handle the user's response, you could simply pass the unique key for the object they're approving, plus the response (Accept/Reject), as parameters in the URL. Your Apex application's page would process those parameters and confirm the user's response to them when it displayed the page.

The Apex documentation has good information on forming an Apex URL to show how parameters are passed.

If you need to raise the security level, look into generating a checkpoint value to pass as another parameter, to confirm that someone didn't hack your URL parameter values.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe StewS2 did a good job of answering this question, but I'll provide a little more detail in case you're looking for it. First, you'll need to read up on Understanding URL Syntax with APEX:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmdb/understanding-url-syntax.html#GUID-F9B81EAF-D33F-401D-8349-3952DEDA5460

The positions in the URL are:

1. App
2. Page
3. Session
4. Request
5. Debug
6. ClearCache
7. itemNames
8. itemValues
9. PrinterFriendly

In your email, you'll likely add two links, one for "approve" and another for "deny". Let's assume the target app is 101 and the target page is 50. Let's also assume that on page 50, there are items named P50_ID and P50_STATUS.

The link for "approve" would look like this:
https://server.com/ords/f?p=101:50:::::P50_ID,P50_STATUS:123456,APPROVE

And the link for "deny" would look like this:
https://server.com/ords/f?p=101:50:::::P50_ID,P50_STATUS:123456,DENY

Note that the only difference is the value being passed to P50_STATUS in position 8 of the URL.

Because the URLs don't have a session identifier (position 3), a new session will be created and the user will be authenticated prior to viewing page 50. On page 50, you can add On Load processes that look at the value of P50_ID and P50_STATUS and do whatever needs to be done from there.

Be sure to handle edge cases, such as if a user later denies somethings that's been approved or vice versa.

Also, take security into account to ensure that if the email is accidentally forwarded the new recipient can't do anything with it. Start with authentication and authorization schemes, but you can get more granular if needed in the On Load process.